# jQuery .append() after offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

`<div id="testcase">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>`

I would like to add this: `<span>` with an offset.

So when I for example would have the JS function: `addSpan(4)` this would happen:
`<div id="testcase">abcd<span>efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>`

To visualise what I'm looking for:

```
function addSpan(i){
    $('#testcase').append('<span>', i);
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more details to make your question clear.!

Comment: where would the end span go?

Comment: Let's make a step back: why do you need a span? For structural or for styling purposes?

Comment: The I is to 'visualise' what I want. And the empty span is just 'some element' it can be some text or whatever. What I'm looking for is a way to add something to (in this case `#testcase`) *after* a given offset

Comment: The answer is here :-)

Comment: Ok, see what you mean but then: where would the end span go?

Comment: Dont know your problem guys he stated his case in javascript and want a jquery equivalent to insert a substring into an existing element at position i. (I think its obivious that i shall be a numeric value representing the position).

Comment: @Steini i was focused on append method and invalid HTML. BTW, where do you see any javascript code attempt to 'convert' into jQuery? That's ok, you get it thought ;)

Comment: @Wolff "So when I for example would have the JS function: addSpan(4)" - I think its pretty obvious.

Comment: @Steini ya my bad, didn't really see it

Comment: It could also have been the function `addMonkey()` and it would add the word *monkey* it was just by manner of speech. (indeed Wolff that's why I wrote: "for example")

Comment: @bvl that's ok but providing as example invalid HTML is never a good example

Comment: Hahaha, jeah, but it isn't about the HTML ;-) I will never, ever, ever, ever use invalid HTML in an *example* ever, ever, ever again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slice and concatinate...

```
function addSpan(i){
    var content = $("#testcase").html();
    var before = content.slice(0, i);
    var after = content.slice(i + 1);
    $("#testcase").html(before + "<span></span>" + after);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another wut i tired **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rys8K/1/)**

```
$("#btn_clck").on('click', function () {
    var gText = $("#testcase").html();
    var getlength = gText.length;
    var finalValue = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < getlength; i++) {
        var setData = gText.charAt(i);
        if (i == 4) {
            finalValue += '<span></span>'
        }
        finalValue += setData;
    }
    $("#testcase").text(finalValue);
});
```

but i think Steini's answers was better